# SQL a JSON no exporta todos los registros - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json

Estoy haciendo una consulta sql a una base de datos con 148 registros y la estoy convirtiendo a json de esta forma:

```
select * from db.Datos for json path
```

y el json que me entrega solo tiene unos pocos registros, incluso el ultimo aparece incompleto. No encuentro una parametro para for json path que sea algo como incluir todos los registros o similar, que puede estar pasando?

**EDITADO**

con esta forma logro llegar hasta el registro 72 de los 148:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max);

SET @json = (SELECT * FROM tablas
               FOR JSON AUTO)

SELECT @json;
```

pero sigo sin poder recuperar todos los registros.
El tema es que son 148 registros, los cuales tienen esta informacion cada uno:

```
{
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Especificacion": "Potencia: 100 W"
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Dimmable: NO "
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Tensión: 100~277 VCA"
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Eficiencia: 150\/160 Lm\/W"
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Cantidad de leds: 240 "
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Protección: IP66 "
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "Factor de Potencia: >0,95 "
      },
      {
        "Especificacion": "C.R.I.: >70 "
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https:\/\/electrobroker.com\/admin\/fotos\/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHNSA 100-150-200-240.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https:\/\/electrobroker.com\/admin\/fotos\/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHNSA.png"
      }
    ],
    "Variantes": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Variante": "120 º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Variante": "60 º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Variante": "90 º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Temperatura de color",
        "Variante": "4000 ºK"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Temperatura de color",
        "Variante": "5700 ºK"
      }
    ],
    "Embarque": [
      {
        "Embarque": "Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) MAY-2020",
        "Cierre": "15\/3\/2021",
        "ArriboEstimado": "13\/6\/2021",
        "FOB": 33.95,
        "MOQ": 100
      }
```

me parece que no es la gran cosa como para que lo limite

**SOLUCION FINAL**
Con cambiarle en las opciones de query:Grid:non xml data: de 65535 a 150000 recupere los 148 registros

Comment: y si usas auto en lugar de path?

Comment: Será que hay algún dato que contiene algún carácter que pueda está rompiendo el formato JSON?

Comment: @gbianchi con auto paso lo mismo

Comment: @Alfabravo, no, porque cuando saco individualmente el registro donde se queda sale sin problema

Comment: Y desde dónde haces la consulta? en tu aplicación? en un cliente como SSMS?

Comment: En SSMS directo

Comment: `for json` siempre incluye todos los registros que devuelve la consulta. Sospecho que, ya que ves _incompleto_ el último (y aunque no lo mencionas, tampoco se _cierran_ los objetos y arreglos, lo que está ocurriendo es que el cliente que utilizas está cortando la cadena que el motor SI está produciendo. **Solución**, cambia de cliente o configúralo para que no corte una cadena larga.

Comment: @jachguate lo abro con vs code. Tambien probe abrirlo en jsonviewer y da el mismo resultado. He leido por ahi, y no pude volver a encontrarlo, que alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y le recomendaban algo asi como asignar el json a una variable...no le preste demasiada importancia en ese momento porque no tenia todavia el problema

Comment: por otro lado de los 148 solo me entrega 2 registro y el tercero incompleto, lo que note es que cuanto mas data tiene cada busqueda menos registros me toma, es como que estubiera limitado a cierta cantidad de caracteres. Lo extraño es que si fuese un problema comun, estaria lleno de soluciones al googlearlo, y no es asi...

Comment: En SSMS puedes obtener los resultados a una rejilla, a texto plano o a un archivo. El primero no tiene sentido, el segundo podría cortar los datos (aunque probablemente no), pero como sea, sugiero que uses el tercero. (En Inglés, con atajos estándar, con [shift][crtl][F] puedes activarlo, o en el menú _Query_/_Results to..._  ¿Lo guarda _cortado_?

Comment: lo guarda con mil errores, y tampoco esta la cantidad total de registros. La opcion grilla es la unica que da un resultado limpio, aunque recorta los registros

Comment: Por favor, agrega una respuesta completa en el campo respuesta.

Comment: ¿con mil errores? ¿cuáles?

Comment: @jachguate le agrega corchetes y llaves donde no deberia. Pero ya esta solucionado, como puse en la edicion, asignando la query a una variable me daba 72 registros de los 148, luego le cambie las opciones de query subiendo al doble la longitud de non xml data y trajo todo el jason completo